# SSL Certificate not verifying in Google Chrome

Tags: http, google-chrome, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've bought an SSL certificate for a website.

When I access the webpage in chrome I get a message saying...

[image]

I tried removing all reference to static 'http' urls, but I still get the error. Has anyone had a similar issue. How can I make sure the website is marked as a secure connection?

UPDATE..

When I click on the link below it works, but if I enter the url manually it doesn't work? I've cleared the cache and tried on multiple computers.

https://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com

UPDATE 2..

Removed Google Analytics, and cleared cache to see if that was the problem. Same problem occurred. Then added Analytics back as to keep tracking trafic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely still resources which are loaded from http.
My chrome shows the same error message.

On Windows in chrome hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) switch to the resources or network tab then reload the page an look for your self.

https://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com/contact ist not working there a some javascripts from bing and virtualearth.net.

Comment: to get rid of the yellow triangle there are some images or css files left e.g. http://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com/headers/news.jpg also chrome seems to have en interesting behavior if it gets red it stays red until you close the tab and open it in a new one, for yellow warning it updates when surfing between your subpages

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and looks like it is working. Did you clear the cache of the browser?

// EDIT
I looked into your code and this might be what are causing your problems.(I use an HTTPS enforcer so I am only guessing)
utm.gif">http://google-analytics.com/_utm.gif

Comment: I cleared the cache and tried on 3 computers. https://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com

Comment: Stranger still When I click the link from this site it works... but if I put it in manually to the address bar it doesn't :S

Comment: What is that code. The Google Analytics at the bottom of the site?

Comment: Most likely yes. It is the only external resource I found.